# Error en E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview, mvp

Estoy intentando hacer una aplicaciòn con clean architecture y MVP y patròn repository,(debo aclarar que soy nuevo en esto)  tengo 5 clases 
la de la vista, presenter, interactor, repositorio, y el adapter les adjunto el còdigo de cada clase necesito mostrar en pantalla una lista con un recyclerview pero sigo recibiendo el error **E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout**
y no muestra la lista
de ante mano muchas gracias

Vista Dashboard()

```
 @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    adapter = DashboardAdapter(context!!)
    recycler_accountant.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, OrientationHelper.VERTICAL, false)
    recycler_accountant.adapter = adapter
}

override fun SendDataAccountantToPresenter() {
    presenter.getDataAccountantToInteractor()
}

override fun SendDataAccountantToAdapter(mutableList: MutableList<Accountant>) {
    Log.d(ContentValues.TAG, "datos obtenidos en la vista $mutableList")
    adapter.setDataList(mutableList)
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Presenter DashboardPresenter()

```
class DashboardPresenter(dashboardInteactor: DashboardAccountantInteractor) : DashboardContract.DashboardPresenter {

var dashboardInt: DashboardAccountantInteractor? = null
var viewdp: DashboardContract.DashboardView? = null

init {
    dashboardInt = dashboardInteactor
}


override fun getDataAccountantToInteractor() {
    Log.d(ContentValues.TAG, "entro en el metodo getDataAccountantToInteractor() del presenter ")
    dashboardInt?.getAccountantDataToRepository()?.observe(Dashboard(), Observer {
        viewdp?.SendDataAccountantToAdapter(it)
    })


}
```

Interactor DashboardAccountantImpl()

```
class DashboardAcoountantImpl : DashboardAccountantInteractor {
override fun getAccountantDataToRepository(): MutableLiveData<MutableList<Accountant>> {
    val accountantRepository = AccountRepositoryImpl()
    val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
    val exception = FirebaseAuthException("002", "user don't Auth")
    val mutableListData = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Accountant>>()

    if (user != null) {
        accountantRepository.getAccountantData().observeForever { accountantlist ->

            mutableListData.value = accountantlist
            Log.d(ContentValues.TAG, "datos obtenidos en el interactor ${mutableListData.value}")
        }



    } else {
        Log.d(ContentValues.TAG, "Para ingresar sus datos debe ser un usuario registrado", exception)
    }
    return mutableListData
}
```

}

Repositorio AccountRepositoryImpl()

```
override fun getAccountantData():LiveData<MutableList<Accountant>>  {
    val mutableData = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Accountant>>()
    val listData = mutableListOf<Accountant>()
    db.collection("accountant").get().addOnSuccessListener { querySnapshot ->

        if (querySnapshot.isEmpty) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Error obteniendo datos de los documentos")
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "datos obtenidos con exito desde firestore al repositorio")
            for (document in querySnapshot) {
                val name = document.getString("name")
                val lastname = document.getString("lastname")
                val city = document.getString("city")
                val accountant = Accountant(document.getString("id")!!, "$name","$lastname",
                        document.getString("email")!!,document.getString("phone")!!,city!!,
                        document.getString("address")!!,document.getString("professional_card")!!)


                listData.add(accountant)
            }
        }


        mutableData.value = listData


    }

    return mutableData
}
```

Adapter DashboardAdapter()

```
class DashboardAdapter(private val context:Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<DashboardAdapter.Viewholder>() {

private var datalist: MutableList<Accountant> = mutableListOf()

fun setDataList(data:MutableList<Accountant>){
    datalist = data
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): Viewholder {
    val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_accountant, parent, false)
    return Viewholder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return if (datalist.size > 0) datalist.size else 0
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Viewholder, position: Int) {
    val accountant = datalist[position]
    holder.bindView(accountant)
}

inner class Viewholder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    fun bindView(accountant: Accountant) {
        val fullname = accountant.name + accountant.lastname
        itemView.labl_name.text = fullname
        itemView.txt_city.text = accountant.city

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Qué error encuentras? Por favor, edita tu pregunta con el enlace Editar y añade la info correspondiente

Comment: el error que me muestra el log es el siguiente :  E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Answer (score 0):

Cambia el mètodo `getItemCount()` del Adapter a solo retornar la medida del listado datalist:

```
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    //return if (datalist.size > 0) datalist.size else 0
      return datalist.size 
}
```

La orientaciòn de tu `LinearLayoutManager` definela de esta forma:

```
recycler_accountant.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
```

Comment: muchas gracias pero sigo teniendo el mismo problema no se lista la información y sigo obteniendo el mismo error en el logcat `E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout`